# Pre-configured Environment Variable in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker

I am running Jenkins though the docker image.

I want my Jenkins Installation to come up with few pre configured enviroment variables.

Is there any way I can copy some of my environment variables, so that when I bring my jenkins up, it should come with these pre-configured environment variables ?

TIA.

Comment: docker run -e myVariable=myValue may be help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of available environment variables is available here: https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

**Update**

If you want to add your own environment variables you need to build your own jenkins image. You can do this by extending an existing image or modify the official docker build project provided by jenkins on [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker).

Docker has a nice tutorial on how to build images [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/#/undefined).

In this specific case you need to modify the docker entrypoint file to retrieve and replace the environment variables where needed. For jenkins, the docker entrypoint file is located in `/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh`.

Comment: I want to add some of my own customized environment variables with some fixed values other than the ones which are available.

Comment: @Akki see the updated answer. Doing what you want may not be as straight forward for a beginner.