# Pre Configured Environment variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker

I am running Jenkins though the docker image.

I want my Jenkins Installation to come up with few pre configured enviroment variables.

Is there any way I can copy some of my environment variables, so that when I bring my jenkins up, it should come with these pre-configured environment variables ?

Or 
Where are the environment variables stored in the Jenkins installation ?

TIA.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/41935327/2853903

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre-configured Environment Variable in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935327/pre-configured-environment-variable-in-jenkins)